# How can I break out of an each() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML + JS. I want the toggleButton to only toggle the first io-section-header. Eventually I will have multiple toggleButton's that will toggle a unique ul.

How can I achieve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div><span>Section 1</span></div>
  <div class="io-section-header">
  <ul>
    <li class="advanced">Accounts</li>
    <li class="advanced">People</li>
    <li class="advanced">companies</li>
    <li class="basic">She</li>
  </ul>
   <div><span>Section 2</span></div>
   <div class="io-section-header">
    <ul>
    <li class="advanced">Accounts</li>
    <li class="advanced">People</li>
    <li class="advanced">companies</li>
    <li class="basic">P</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="toggleButton">Collapse</div>

<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('.toggleButton').click(function () {  
            var currentText = $(this).text();
            if(currentText === "Collapse")
                $(this).text("Expand");
            else
                $(this).text("Collapse");

            /*$('.io-section-header').each(function() {
                $("li").siblings(".advanced").toggle('fast',function(){});
            });*/

            $('.io-section-header li').siblings(".advanced").toggle('fast'); 

        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should be able to just return `false` from the callback. A better way would be to simply use `first()` or the `:first` selector. Had no idea you were on SO by the way :)

Comment: Says it right in the [jQuery each docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will toggle the first advanced class in each io-section-header class

```
$('ul li.advanced:first', '.io-section-header').toggle('fast',function(){});
```

This will toggle the first advanced class in the first io-section-header class

```
$('ul li.advanced:first', '.io-section-header:first').toggle('fast',function(){});
```

Comment: The second snippet is more along the lines of what I'm trying to achieve. How can I toggle all of the elements in io-section-header? If I added another toggleButton to toggle the 2nd io-section-header how would that be achieved? If I have N toggle buttons and N io-section-headers?

Comment: you could get the button's index like this - var index = $(".toggleButton").index(this); and than toggle only the one you want like this - $('ul li', '.io-section-header:eq(' + index + ')').toggle('fast',function(){});

Comment: @SheehanAlam: you'll need some way of tracking which toggle buttons are connected to which element. My favourite way is using data attributes with element ids / selectors: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xqNL9/).

Answer (score 4):

From the [`.each()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

Comment: Even when I add return false() to my loop, it still toggles both of my divs. Can you show me an example?

Comment: The code using .each() is still using `$("li").siblings(".advanced")`. This will match **all** `<li>`s on the page, not just the ones under `this`. For that you'd have to use $(this).find('li')…, although a better solution would likely be using a selector that only matches what you want instead of breaking out of an iteration.

Answer (score 0):

[`return false`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is all you need; why aren't you using `first()`?

Comment: Even when I add return false() to my loop, it still toggles both of my divs. Can you show me an example? Using first will always return the first ul. Eventually I want to have multiple toggleButtons that will hide/show its associated ul